# Recursive call - being made several times

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am working on a recursive call (Node.js), and I have some issues with it. The return is being called not once, but depending how many times if statement matched:

My Code:

```
//This is class method
calculateStats (selectedStatus, allStatuses) {

 allStatuses.forEach((productStatus) => {
 if (productStatus.product.id === selectedStatus.product.parentId) {   
      //Some other function calls and small calculation
      //I we ended up here three times
      //Return statement will be called three times
      return this.calculateStats(productStatus, allStatuses);
     }

 });

 return this.wrapper(this.startPoint, this.finalProductStatus);     
}
```

For example if the code ends inside if statement, there is couple of function calls that make some other calculation and assignments. Now, if the code ends inside if lets say 5 times, return statement will be called 5 times. I expect it to be called only once.

What am I missing here?

Comment: foreach will be called for all elements and your recursive call will be called for all elements matching, so... you could have some sort of boolean variable like "bFound" and only make the recursive call if none has been done before. You could also call return after the first call inside the if. This will break the "loop"

Comment: @Douwe de Hann adding the return did not solve the problem. Behaviour is still the same.